# How to convert stored procedure to select table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that returns some rows like this :

```
code
-----
one
two
three
```

I want a select witch return this result:

```
-------------
code |title  |
-----|-------|
one  |one    |
two  |two    |
three|three  |
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a temptable and insert the result of the procedure into it and then write the required query on it:

```
create table #tbl (col varchar(50))
go
insert into #tbl
exec Your_stored_procedure
go
select col as code, col as title from #tbl
drop table #tbl
```